# Get body json specific data in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I use the req res for node js from the following module and I want to send in **post message body** the following json

```
{
    "Actions": [
        {
            "file1": {
                "name": "file 1",
                "content": "file 2 content"
            },
            "file2": {
                "name": "file 2",
                "content": "file 2 content"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get from the req body the name and the content

I use the create server and there I've req and res
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

UPDATE

this is my code

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),

    url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

   var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0];


    console.log(req.body);
```

Comment: Can't understand your question, you need to send or get? It's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @Michelem - I send this body content in post message (via postman)and I want to get in my node js app the name and the content of each file...

Comment: It should be `req.body.Actions[0].file1.content`

Comment: I cant understand your problem, What do you want to ask?

Comment: @Michelem- thanks I try exactly like you write and  I got error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'Actions' of undefined   any idea?

Comment: Try `console.log(req.body)` to look if it is like you wish

Comment: @Michelem - thanks but somehow I got undfiend for console.log(req.body) what it can be ?I use json in the raw(postman) & content-Type application/text-enriched

Comment: You have to show us your Node.js code, please update your question with that.

Comment: You should use `express` with `body-parser` modules. look at example here: http://code.runnable.com/U0sU598vXio2uD-1/example-reading-form-input-with-express-4-0-and-body-parser-for-node-js

Comment: @Michelem - this is not overkill to use express and http-proxy ?there is other way to do that ?

Comment: You should use Express in ALL your Node.js web app, it is built exactly for it. I wouldn't suggest any other way. Use Express (and body-parser).

Comment: @Michelem - thanks but how should i use both ?express and http-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Node's http API is awful. To get the body, you need to listen for data events and build the body string yourself.

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var body = '';
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json.Actions[0].file1.content);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

I highly recommend using something like Express that hides all these details.

Comment: It's the only way to get body with the node http library. I recommend using Express instead.

Comment: Thanks Matthew but how should I use express with the http-proxy